How to update db data when moving an item in a list?

I am using swiftui to create a list and using .onMove to move items.
I want to update the db information stored in sqlite when moving items.
I am using the stephencelis/SQLite.swift library for sqlite.
I have created the code as below.
But the code below updates the entire list after the item is moved.
Is this method efficient? Or is there another way? For example, updating the moved item and the item to the destination.
Can I get a better code that updates the db of sqlite when moving items in the list?
Thank you.
@State private var listItem = [Item]()

ForEach(listItem) { item in
        ListCell(
            item: item,
            onDelete: { deleteItem(item) }
        )
}
.onMove(perform: moveItem)

func moveItem(from source : IndexSet, to destination : Int)
{
    var tempDataSet : [Item] = listItem

    listItem.move(fromOffsets : source, toOffset : destination)

    for (index, item) in listItem.enumerated()
    {
        dbManager.updateDbData(listItem[index].date, listItem[index].content, listItem[index].amount, tempDataSet[index].id)
    }
    listItem = dbManager.loadDbData()

}

func updateDbData(_ date : String, _ content : String, _ amount : String, _ id : Int)
{
    do
    {

    let update = MainTable.filter(dbId == id)

    try db.run(update.update(dbContent < -content, dbDate < -date, dbAmount < -amount))
    }
    catch (let err)
    {
        print("updateDbData err = \(err)")
    }
}


I'm not familiar with the stephencelis/SQLite.swift library, but
you could try using this for index in source {  dbManager.updateDbData(listItem[index].date, listItem[index].content, listItem[index].amount, listItem[index].id) } to process just the moved items.

Your code looks quite strange are you sure it’s working correctly? What are you sorting the list on, the id property?

@workingdog support Ukraine - There was an error in the code, so I re-uploaded it. It works, but there is a flickering problem like the added gif file.

@Joakim Danielson - Sorry, I added the code and pictures. The order property is currently not there. When moving, the entire data is changed. The problem is that when moving, it blinks like the picture.

You should not update all objects when only some are changed, it’s wrong in many ways and one is performance. And you need a specific property for the sort order, don’t reuse the id property for this (if that is what is going on now).

@Joakim Danielson - I tried updating only the db list within the moved range, not the entire list. However, the data of listItem should also be updated, but the moment the listItem is updated, a flickering symptom appears as in the picture. I think the onMove function deletes the data before moving and adds data to the newly moved location. However, since there is no function to add data in db, I need to update all the data between the moved range. Can I see an example or github for moving an item to a list and updating the db?

These are two separate concerns, handling the database update and updating the UI and I think you should approach them separately. ”onMove function deletes the data”, no it doesn’t. ”no function to add data in db”, this doesn’t make sense. Like I said the database (data source) and the UI (code) are two different things but you seem to confuse them or see them as one and the same thing.

@Joakim Danielson - Thank you so much for your reply
I am planning to migrate from uikit to swiftui
I am confused now is there any place where there is example sample code?
